# How to create such element(adaptive)?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I can't figure out how to create such an element, in order to the distance between points is always adapted to the screen size.

[image: Task]

Here is result of my code:

```css
.line-list {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  
  padding: 0;
}

.line-list__item {
  position: relative;

  display: inline-block;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;

  border: 2px solid #00bfa5;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #fafafa;
}

.line-list__item:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 45%;
  left: 100%;

  display: block;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 2px;

  background-color: #00bfa5;
  z-index: -1;
}

.line-list__item:last-child:after { content: none; }
```

```html
<ul class="line-list">
    <li class="line-list__item">&nbsp;</li>     
    <li class="line-list__item">&nbsp;</li>     
</ul>
```

Comment: Please show us some code.

Comment: adapted to screen size means? is it changes with change in screen size?

Comment: Changes with change in screen size - yeah, exactly.

Comment: can you elaborate what are you trying to achieve. Your snippet is working fine with responsiveness.. Do you want to change circle size..or anything.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tried on your code, but made this:--
Used relative unit vw for margin between points.

```css
#bt1{
 width:20px;
 height:20px;
 margin-left:10vw;
}


#bt2{
 width:20px;
 height:20px;
 margin-left:60vw;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" id="bt1">

</button>

<button type="button" id="bt2">

</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Will work on browsers only(not on fiddle or SO)

css

```
*{margin:0;padding:0;}
.element{
  position:relative;
  background-color:green;
  height:2px;
  width:calc(100vw - 40px -2px);
  margin:10px 20px;
}
.element::after,.element::before{
  content:'a';
  color:transparent;
  position:absolute;
  border: 2px solid green;
  width:20px;
  height:20px;
  border-radius:100%;
  top:-10px;
}
.element::after{
  right:-22;
}
.element::before{
  left:-22;
}
```

html

```
<div class="element"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I decided.

```css
    .line-list {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-between;
      
      padding: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
    }

    .line-list__item {
      position: relative;

      display: inline-block;
      width: 15px;
      height: 15px;

      border: 2px solid #00bfa5;
      border-radius: 50%;
      background-color: #fafafa;
    }

    .line-list__item:after {
      content: '';
      position: absolute;
      top: 45%;
      left: 100%;

      display: block;
      width: 100vw;
      height: 2px;

      background-color: #00bfa5;
      z-index: -1;
    }

    .line-list__item:last-child:after { content: none; }
```

```html
<ul class="line-list">
   <li class="line-list__item">&nbsp;</li>     
   <li class="line-list__item">&nbsp;</li>     
 </ul>
```